# Upgrading to Ubuntu desktop 14.10 from 14.04 failed because of loop between services

Tags: upgrade, crash, 14.10

While upgrading most of it seemed smooth till it abruptly stalled  and refused to continue . Video driver fell back to framebuffer and neither nouveau or nividia modules were loading  and display was a mess

Looking at the logs spewed out on the console it seemed there was a race between 2 services jetty and mediatomb ,both of which I had installed in 14.04 . Snippet of log from /var/log/apt-term.log

**** LOG *******

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade/20141025-0331/apt-term.log:insserv: warning: script 'jetty' missing LSB tags and overrides
/var/log/dist-upgrade/20141025-0331/apt-term.log:insserv: There is a loop between service mediatomb and jetty if stopped
/var/log/dist-upgrade/20141025-0331/apt-term.log:insserv:  loop involving service jetty at depth 2
/var/log/dist-upgrade/20141025-0331/apt-term.log:insserv: Stopping jetty depends on mediatomb and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```

****** END ***********

Answer (score 3):

Managed to resolve by

- Removing the 2 conflicting scripts from /etc/init.d
- Reinstalling nvidia drivers using apt-get install  nvidia-331-dev

After installing the nvidia driver the installation seemed to proceed from where it left off .But no clean up happened and I had to force clean the apt cache to free up space .

The loop condition between services  can best handled by utpoic ugrader as it seems to be related to upgrade of core system OR kernel .

Comment: in my case is was an extra script belonging to anyconnect. I've deleted it like you said and was able to do an upgrade from command line. But to be able to start the X GUI I had to uninstall the AMD fglrx drivers.

Comment: In my case Xgui started in Fbramebuffer mode with display corruption and missing special effects . Its possible mine worked because it was an older  Nvidia card .